# What is the ViewControllerRegistry used for in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

From [docs.spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewControllerRegistry.html):

> Stores registrations of view controllers. A view controller does
>   nothing more than return a specified view name. It saves you from
>   having to write a controller when you want to forward the request
>   straight through to a view such as a JSP.

But what does this mean exactly? Would anyone please provide some examples?